# Can't Set text of a button coming from a database

Tags: android, sqlite, button

Can anyone please help to my little problem here. whenever im trying to set the text of the button coming from a db it never shows up but txt for the textview was displayed.

Activity

```
package com.iamrock.louie.saver.EasyMode;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.List;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.iamrock.louie.saver.Choices.Correct;
import com.iamrock.louie.saver.Choices.Lose;
import com.iamrock.louie.saver.Choices.Wrong;
import com.iamrock.louie.saver.R;


public class EasyGame extends Activity {

    ImageView eview;
    int x;
    List<Question> quesList;
    public int qid;
    TextView txtQuestion;
    Button choice, choices;
    Question currentQ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy_game);


        qid = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("asd");


        DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
        quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
        txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.questtxt1);
        choice=(Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        choices=(Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);

        condition();
        if(x<5){
            txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
            choice.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
            choices.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
            //qid++;
        }

        choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Button answer= (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice1);
                if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
                {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(EasyGame.this, Correct.class);
                    intent.putExtra("asd", qid);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else
                {//wrong answer statement
                    Intent intent = new Intent(EasyGame.this, Wrong.class);
                    intent.putExtra("asd", qid);
                    intent.putExtra("zxc", x+=1);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            }
        });


        choices.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Button answer= (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice2);
                if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(EasyGame.this, Correct.class);
                    intent.putExtra("asd", qid);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(EasyGame.this, Wrong.class);
                    intent.putExtra("asd", qid);
                    intent.putExtra("zxc", x+=1);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.easy_game, menu);
        return true;
    }



    private void condition()
    {

        if(x==0)
        {
            eview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.puso1);
            eview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        if (x==1)
        {
            eview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.puso1);
            eview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        if (x==2)
        {
            eview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.puso2);
            eview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        if (x==3)
        {
            eview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.puso3);
            eview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        if (x==4)
        {
            eview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.puso4);
            eview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        if (x==5)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EasyGame.this,Lose.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            eview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.puso5);
            eview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }

    }





    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.iamrock.louie.homepage.HardGame"
android:background="@drawable/quest_bg"
>




<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="choice1"
    android:id="@+id/choice1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="#f1fa02"
    android:layout_above="@+id/choice2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/questtxt1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/questtxt1"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="choice2"
    android:id="@+id/choice2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textColor="#f1fa02"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/choice1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/choice1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="question"
    android:id="@+id/questtxt1"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/puso4"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/puso4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/puso2" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/puso5"
    android:src="@drawable/life"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/puso4"
    android:src="@drawable/life"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/puso5"
    android:layout_marginRight="1px"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/puso3"
    android:src="@drawable/life"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_below="@+id/puso5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/puso2"
    android:src="@drawable/life"
    android:layout_below="@+id/puso5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/puso1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/puso1" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/puso1"
    android:src="@drawable/life"
    android:layout_below="@+id/puso2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<com.iamrock.louie.saver.Animation.GifViewQ
    android:id="@+id/gifviewq"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/choice1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/choice1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/choice1"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    />
```

Here is the database and helper which i think was the prob

```
package com.iamrock.louie.saver.EasyMode;


public class Question {
    private int ID;
    private String QUESTION;
    private String OPTA;
    private String OPTB;
    private String ANSWER;
    public Question()
    {
        ID=0;
        QUESTION="";
        OPTA="";
        OPTB="";
        ANSWER="";
    }
    public Question(String qUESTION, String oPTA, String oPTB,
                    String aNSWER) {
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
        OPTA = oPTA;
        OPTB = oPTB;
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }
    public int getID()
    {
        return ID;
    }
    public String getQUESTION() {
        return QUESTION;
    }
    public String getOPTA() {
        return OPTA;
    }
    public String getOPTB() {
        return OPTB;
    }
    public String getANSWER() {
        return ANSWER;
    }
    public void setID(int id)
    {
        ID=id;
    }
    public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION) {
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
    }
    public void setOPTA(String oPTA) {
        OPTA = oPTA;
    }
    public void setOPTB(String oPTB) {
        OPTB = oPTB;
    }
    public void setANSWER(String aNSWER) {
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }
}
```

helper

```
package com.iamrock.louie.saver.EasyMode;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "saver";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions();
        //db.close();
    }



    private void addQuestions()
    {
        Question q1=new Question("What are you going to do when earthquake" +
                "  occurs and you're top in the building?",
                "   A. find something e.g.\n" +
                "           table that you can hide",
                "        B. stay on the top\n" +
                "            of the buiding",
                "   A. find something e.g.\n" +//answer
                "           table that you can hide");
        this.addQuestion(q1);

        Question q2=new Question("Sometimes there are small tremors that occur preceding an earthquake. \n" +
                "These are called “      ”?\n", "A. Foreshocks", "B. Aftershocks",
                "A. Foreshocks");//answer
        this.addQuestion(q2);

    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
// Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
// Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }



    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
//SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
// Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
// Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
// return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats is the problem ? You got an exception ? if yes please provide logcat result  , Please explain exactly what happens when you want set the text to button

Comment: @MortezaSoleimani.the buttons and textview text should be automatically set coming from the database. but when i try to run the program it only sets the text  of the textview and the buttons missing. Thank you for  your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

before this code you have not assigned the value of x

```
if(x<5){
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        choice.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        choices.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        //qid++;
    }
```

assign value to x before this condition. this can solve your problem.

Comment: it doesnt affect the program sir. because it is already declared.

Comment: but tell me at this condition what is the value of x?

Comment: it is probably zero. when you declare it as it is. it is automatically zero. it is globally declared at the activity. sir anything else your seeing wrong please do inform me in instant because i need this for tomorrow. thank you very much

Comment: the just change int x=0;